# CSS @media option not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the CSS @media option but I am experiencing some issues.
I have three options, landscape, portrait, and mobile.  The mobile only activates vertically but horizontally it doesn't activate (basically get the landscape option).

Here is the CSS:

```
@media (orientation:landscape) {
/* some css */
}

@media (orientation:portrait) {
/* some more css */
}

@media mobile {
/* more css */
/* basically the same as vertical */
}
```

How do I do this properly? I want my mobile option to be the same as my portrait option.

Comment: It is to hard to say without seeing some style properties and the end result you are seeing (one or two would be fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try following:

```
    /* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

For mobile screens, i think you need to define minimum resolution like this:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Here is what I have now:

media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
 
}

media screen and (orientation:portrait), handheld
{
 
}
For some reason, on handheld or mobile only portrait alignment works and landscape is still displayed as horizontal.

Comment: Unless you have a reason otherwise, why not use "all"?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `screen and`...

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}

/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

iPhones normally scale the website, so you also need this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

For iPhones running a version before 4.0, you can use the following

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}

/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```